# Delete rows when certain columns are empty

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone what is wrong with this code? It is supposed to delete rows when columns A through F are empty. Thank you

```
Sub range_reporter()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row
    For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        If Cells(n, "A") & Cells(n, "B") & Cells(n, "C") & Cells(n, "D") & Cells(n, "E") & Cells(n, "F") = "" Then
            Cells(n, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're using improper syntax for "AND" (The "&" character is for concatenation). Take a look at the code below, I just tested it and it works fine.

```
Sub range_reporter()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row

    For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        If Cells(n, "A") = "" And Cells(n, "B") = "" And Cells(n, "C") = "" And Cells(n, "D") = "" And Cells(n, "E") = "" And Cells(n, "F") = "" Then
            Cells(n, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next n

End Sub
```